# Sorting the date column on a pandas dataframe that is not in date time format and has format mmm dd, yyyy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi all I am working with a pandas dataframe that contains a date column. I would like to sort this column by date in ascending order, meaning that the most recent date is at the bottom of the dataframe. The problem that I am running into is that the date column displays the dates in the following format:
"Nov 3, 2020"

how can I sort these dates, the suggested advice that I have found online is to convert the date into a date time format and then sort then change it back to this format. Is there a more simple way to do this? I have tried this

```
new_df.sort_values(by=["Date"],ascending=True)
```

where new_df is the dataframe, but this does not seem to work.
Any ideas on how can do this? I essentially want the output to have something like

```
Date
----
Oct 31, 2020
Nov 1, 2020
Nov 12,2020
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are you sure your column Date is datetime? new_df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(new_df['Date'])

Comment: @adhg no as I mentioned, in the title and in the description, it is not date time

Comment: so the most simple way is to convert it to datetime. Unless I didn't understand the presented problem. (check the code I provided in the comment)

Comment: Yes, I saw that the easiest way to sort would be using datetime, now question was more so if there was a way to just sort directly without converting to date time, because I want to keep the present format after sorting, not the date time format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reformat the date column first, then convert to datetime, and then sort:

```
dates = ['Nov 1, 2020','Nov 12,2020','Oct 31, 2020']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':dates, 'Col1':[2,3,1]})

#        Date      Col1
# 0 Nov 1, 2020     2
# 1 Nov 12,2020     3
# 2 Oct 31, 2020    1

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x.replace(',',' ').split())))

df = df.sort_values('Date')

#        Date     Col1
# 2 2020-10-31      1
# 0 2020-11-01      2
# 1 2020-11-12      3

# and if you want to get the dates back in their original format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x: "{} {}, {}".format(x.month_name()[:3],x.day,x.year))


#        Date     Col1
# 2 Oct 31, 2020    1
# 0 Nov 1, 2020     2
# 1 Nov 12, 2020    3
```

Comment: This seems to be the idea that I had in mind, however my concern was that I wanted the format to remain as for example "Nov 1, 2020", so given you're proposed solution I would have to convert back to this format after sorting, is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Just updated my answer to convert back to the original date format :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(by = "Date", key = pd.to_datetime)
```